# Python recursive function definition using variable raises no error?

Tags: python, function, recursion

```
def f(): 
    return f()
```

This will give me an error if I try to call f()

```
def f(): 
    return var
var = f()
```

This will return 1 when I call f().

What's the difference? And where did the value 1 come from?

Comment: the return 1 is the code of the program failing

Comment: variable `var` is not declared before usage.  This raises an exception, which causes the `python` program to have  a non-zero exit code. are you running it then typing `echo $?`

Comment: @rhubarbdog this in fact is not the reason. Function definitions allow usage of variables that are not yet defined. There are many SO answers on this.

Comment: You may define a function to use a variable that is not defined yet, but it has to be defined at the time of execution which is not the case here.

Comment: are you sure i get exception: global var is not defined.  if var is an object you don't need the `global var` line in function `f()`'s definition

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say. Python tries to access `var` but there is no variable `var`, so what else could it do other than throwing an error?

Comment: You must have defined a global variable `var=1` elsewhere. If you remove it (with `del var`), your second fragment will fail.

Comment: You guys are right. I forgot that I defined var before. That’s why it was returning 1 in the second case. I should have gotten a NameError of var being not defined